# How can i solve this form validation problem in react jsx?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to do a validation form in react but I'm having a lot of problems since I added saving user data for registration.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./registerstyle.css";
import EyeIcon from "./EyeIcon.png";
import EyeIconHide from "./EyeIconHide.png";
import { signup } from "../../api/client";

function RegisterPage() {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [showConfirmPassword, setShowConfirmPassword] = useState(false);
  const [confirmPasswordVisible, setConfirmPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [nameEmpty, setNameEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [confirmPasswordEmpty, setconfirmPasswordEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [emailEmpty, setEmailEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [passwordEmpty, setPasswordEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [newsletter, setNewsletter] = useState(false); // Aggiunto lo stato per la checkbox

  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);
  const [cpass, setCpass] = useState(null);
  const user = { name: name, email: email, password: password, cpass: cpass };



  const handleShowPassword = () => {
    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
    setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible);
  };

  const handleShowConfirmPassword = () => {
    setShowConfirmPassword(!showConfirmPassword);
    setConfirmPasswordVisible(!confirmPasswordVisible);
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Verifica se i campi email e password sono vuoti
    if (!e.target.email.value) {
      setEmailEmpty(true);
      console.log("email True");
    } else {
      setEmailEmpty(false);
      console.log("email False");
    }

    if (!e.target.name.value) {
      setNameEmpty(true);
    } else {
      setNameEmpty(false);
    }

    if (!e.target.password.value) {
      setPasswordEmpty(true);
    } else {
      setPasswordEmpty(false);
    }

    if (!e.target.confirmPassword.value) {
      setconfirmPasswordEmpty(true);
    } else {
      setconfirmPasswordEmpty(false);
    }
  };

  const handleNewsletterChange = (e) => {
    setNewsletter(e.target.checked);
  }; // Funzione per gestire il cambiamento di stato della checkbox

  const passwordInputClass = passwordVisible ? "passwordVisible" : "";
  const confirmPasswordInputClass = confirmPasswordVisible ? "confirmPasswordVisible" : "";

  return (
    <div className="backgroundRegister">
      <div className="titleRegister" />
      <div className="breakRegister" />
      <div className="contlogRegister" />
      <div className="signIn" />
      <form className="formRegister" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <label>
          {/* NAME */}
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} required/>
        </label>
        {nameEmpty && (
          <div>
            <div className="alertCircleName" />
            <div className="FillThisName" />
            <div className="RedRectangleName" />
            <div className="nameError" />
          </div>
        )}
        <br />
        <label>
          {/* EMAIL */}
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} required/>
        </label>
        {emailEmpty && (
          <div>
            <div className="alertCircleEmailRegister" />
            <div className="FillThisEmailRegister" />
            <div className="RedRectangleEmailRegister" />
            <div className="emailErrorRegister" />
          </div>
        )}
        <br />
        <label>
          {/* PASSWORD*/}
          <input
            type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            className={passwordInputClass}
            onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }}
          />
          <img
            src={passwordVisible ? EyeIconHide : EyeIcon}
            alt="eye-icon"
            className="eyeIconRegister1"
            onClick={() => {
              handleShowPassword();
            }}
          />
        </label>
        {passwordEmpty && (
          <div>
            <div className="alertCirclePasswordRegister" />
            <div className="FillThisPasswordRegister" />
            <div className="RedRectanglePasswordRegister" />
            <div className="passwordErrorRegister" />
          </div>
        )}
        <br />
        <label>
          {/* CONFIRM PASSWORD */}
          <input
            type={showConfirmPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            name="confirmPassword"
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            className={confirmPasswordInputClass}
            onChange={(e) => { setCpass(e.target.value) }}
          />
          <img
            src={confirmPasswordVisible ? EyeIconHide : EyeIcon}
            alt="eye-icon"
            className="eyeIconRegister2"
            onClick={() => {
              handleShowConfirmPassword();
            }}
          />
        </label>
        {confirmPasswordEmpty && (
          <div>
            <div className="alertCircleConfirmPassword" />
            <div className="FillThisConfirmPassword" />
            <div className="RedRectangleConfirmPassword" />
            <div className="confirmPasswordError" />
          </div>
        )}
        <br />
        <label> {/* NEWSLETTER */}
          <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" checked={newsletter} onChange={handleNewsletterChange} />
        </label>
        <span className="newsletter">Send me newsletters, tricks and updates. </span>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" className="signInButton" onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          signup(user);
          handleFormSubmit(e);
        }}/>
      </form>
      <div className="registerSign">
        Already have an account? <a href="" className="colorRegister">Login now</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

and this is the code of the signup:

```
import axios from "axios";

// const client = axios.create({
//   baseURL: "http://localhost:9000", // o l'endpoint del vostro backend
//   headers: {
//     "Content-Type": "application/json",
//     //     "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
//   }
// });

// export default client;


async function signup(user) {
  const newUser = JSON.stringify(user);
  console.log("sono dentro la funzione");

  try {
    return await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/signup", newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      return err.response.data;
    } else {
      console.log("Errore:", err.message);
    }
  }
};

async function login(user) {
  const newUser = JSON.stringify(user);
  console.log("sono dentro");

  try {
    return await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", newUser);
    //return await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login",)
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      return err.response.data;
    } else {
      console.log("Errore:", err.message);
    }
  }
};

async function loginOld(credentials) {
  const loginData = JSON.stringify(credentials);
  await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", loginData);
};

export { signup, login };
```

What im expected to happen that when the fields are left empty if you click the button, they pop out of the image I created to circle which field was left empty.Sometimes it gives error like this:

````
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at handleFormSubmit (http://localhost:3000/main.7b4752724621de0f0bc6.hot-update.js:66:25)
    at onClick (http://localhost:3000/main.7b4752724621de0f0bc6.hot-update.js:387:11)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14655:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14699:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14756:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14770:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18914:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18940:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18951:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18960:7)```

I'm desperate and don't really know where to put my hands.
````

Answer (score 1):

Since you're controlling the state of each input you don't need to fetch the values on submissions (even though they way you're trying to do it doesn't work). Instead use the controlled values in your submission callback:

```js
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Verifica se i campi email e password sono vuoti
  if (!email) {
    setEmailEmpty(true);
    console.log("email True");
  } else {
    setEmailEmpty(false);
    console.log("email False");
  }

  if (!name) {
    setNameEmpty(true);
  } else {
    setNameEmpty(false);
  }

  if (!password) {
    setPasswordEmpty(true);
  } else {
    setPasswordEmpty(false);
  }

  if (!confirmPassword) {
    setconfirmPasswordEmpty(true);
  } else {
    setconfirmPasswordEmpty(false);
  }
};
```